# How to remove trailing zeros from an integer (ex: 300 => 3, 4 => 4, 5000 => 5, 6060 => 606?

Tags: java, numeric

The question speaks for itself. How can I do this transformation for any integer number?

```
300 => 3
4 => 4
5000 => 5
6060 => 606
0 => 0
77 => 77
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to divide the number by 10, as long as it is divisible by 10.

This would be an implementation. A number is divisible by 10 if `number % 10 == 0`. We also need to check if the number is `number != 0` to handle the case where the input number would be 0.

```
private static int stripTrailingZeros(int number) {
    while (number != 0 && number % 10 == 0) {
        number /= 10;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using a recursive function and the modulus operator.

```
public static int recursiveZeroStripper(int numberWithTrailingZero) {
    if(numberWithTrailingZero == 0){
        return numberWithTrailingZero;
    }
    if(numberWithTrailingZero%10==0){
        return recursiveZeroStripper(numberWithTrailingZero/10);
    }
    return numberWithTrailingZero;
}
```

Ran that function with

```
    int num=-100;
    System.out.println(recursiveZeroStripper(num));
```

Which resulted in the output of

```
-1
```